# Trying to make a conditional state based on api data using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, state

I am trying to figure out the best way to setup a conditional modal pop up based on weather the response from an api call is null or not. I am most familiar with functional components but here I am working with a component that was built as a class component. I am wondering if I can use the redux store to set up the state or whats the best way to show my `UnsignedNoteModal` if there is data returned from the api call this is the parent component where I need to settup the conditional statement:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    permissions: state.common.permissions,
    currentUser: state.common.currentUser,
    assignedFaxCount: (
      get(state.componentData, `${ASSIGNED_FAX_LIST}.data.items`) || []
    ).filter((i) => !i.complete).length,
    unassignedFaxCount: (
      get(state.componentData, `${UNASSIGNED_FAX_LIST}.data.items`) || []
    ).filter((i) => !i.assigned).length,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({});

class ProviderDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { unsignedNote: true };
    this.toggle = () => this.setState({ unsignedNote: false });
  }

  unassignedFaxList() {
    return (
      <DashboardFaxList
        title="Faxes to forward"
        getItems={api.Faxes.unassignedFaxes}
        currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
        listName={UNASSIGNED_FAX_LIST}
        viewMode={FAX_VIEW_MODE_ASSIGN}
        count={this.props.unassignedFaxCount}
      />
    );
  }

  assignedFaxList() {
    return (
      <DashboardFaxList
        title="Faxes to address"
        getItems={api.Faxes.assignedFaxes}
        currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
        listName={ASSIGNED_FAX_LIST}
        viewMode={FAX_VIEW_MODE_COMPLETE}
        count={this.props.assignedFaxCount}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const canManage = hasPermission(this.props.permissions, PERMISSION_MANAGE);
    const canSeePatients = hasPermission(
      this.props.permissions,
      PERMISSION_SEE_PATIENTS
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.unsignedNote && (
          <UnsignedNoteModal
            onSubmit={this.toggle}
            getList={api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters((e) => e)}
            
          />
        )}
        <NavBar />
        <div className="dashboard-container">
          <h4>
            {" "}
            <div className="header-icon float-left">
              <DashboardIcon />
            </div>{" "}
            Dashboard{" "}
          </h4>
          <Row>
            <Col md={{ size: 8 }}></Col>
            <Col md={{ size: 4 }}>
              {canSeePatients && <PrescriptionErrors />}
              {canManage && this.unassignedFaxList()}
              {(canSeePatients || canManage) && this.assignedFaxList()}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProviderDashboard);
```

Right now I have the state in this component settup to display the modal I've been building but I need to alter it to only show if the api call I am sending in the `UnsignedNoteModal` returns something besides null. Im not sure whats the best route for handling this and any insight into where to begin or how to approach this problem would be awesome.

Comment: Use "getDerivedStateFromProps" to update "this.state.unsignedNote" from props you receive from API. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your state from props using "getDerivedStateFromProps". You need to set "unsignedNote" as "false/true" in "mapStateToProps" depending on your API data.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const {
      unsignedNote = false, // Default value is false
    } = nextProps;
    const {
      unsignedNote: unsignedNoteInState = false, //Default value is false
    } = prevState;

    if(unsignedNote & unsignedNote !== unsignedNoteInState) {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        unsignedNote,
      }
    }
    return prevState;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand why youd say to  update your state from props using "getDerivedStateFromProps". I am trying to figure out how exactly to set up unsigned note as true/false in my mapStateToProps function. Should I be making the api call in the mapStateToProps function? Like `unsignedNote: if(api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters === null){ unsignedNote === false}...etc` ?

Comment: @CourtneyJ, so flow will be like this, 1. You call an action to make API call, 2. Action updates Redux store using Reducers with response from API (May be with data or no data), 3. You will get that data in "state" as parameter of "mapStateToProps". 4. Write logic like `unsignedNote: unsignedEncounters ? false : true,`. (You can write logic base on length of unsignedEncounters if it's an array of checking if it's empty incase of object).